# Bootstrap only collapse for the first item

Tags: html

I'm new to Bootstrap.The Bootstrap collapse only shows on the first item. If I click the button for second item, it will appear on the first item not the second item. I'm not sure what went wrong. The @item.QuizAns will get the QuizAns from the database. I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.
Anybody can show me where's the problem? Here's my code

```
@foreach (var item in Model.QuizQuestions)
{
    <a href="#QuizHint" id="hint" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-info">Hint Quiz</a>
    <div id="QuizHint" class="collapse">                        
        @item.QuizAns
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is happening for ID duplicating issue. In your for each you iterating `id="QuizHint"` and `href="#QuizHint"` multiple time. In single DOM tree same ID can't be duplicate.

To ensure unique ID in DOM tree you should iterate following way:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.QuizQuestions)
{
    <a href="#QuizHint@itemindex" id="hint" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-info">Hint Quiz</a>
    <div id="QuizHint@itemindex" class="collapse">                        
    @item.QuizAns
    </div>
}
```

***@itemindex here I used as a placeholder to just describe you.***

Comment: Yes, basic need ID should be unique like "QuizHint1", "QuizHint2", "QuizHint3".. etc.

Comment: It should not work until make these unique ID I just show you way I don't know you have such @itemindex or not.

Comment: After the item it's working, the button can't close.